# How to pass the correct Model Diction type MVC

Tags: c#, dictionary, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new as MVC 5, I have create a new project and I am setting up the login (With external login).

This is using the VIsual Studio 2013 MVC 5 Application template

So what is happening is when I click the button for a social media login I am getting an error of the wrong model being passed

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'WebPortal.Models.LoginViewModel', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'WebPortal.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel'.

If you need the controls and model code let me know.  But as I said this is the default code that came with the template.  The only things I have been changing is the View at this point to change the look.  And have posted the View Code below.

I think the issue is that since I am starting from the Layout page, the model is never being initiated since there is no model for the layout....  Again I am new so I am only guessing.

Here is the Partial path
"_Layout" -> "_SocialBar"(Partial View) -> "Login"(Partial View) -> "LoginPartial"(Partial View) -> "_ExternalLoginsList"(Partial View)

SocialBar (Partial View)

```
<div class="header-top dark ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-9">
                ...Some Code....
                <!-- header-top-first end -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                @Html.Partial("_Login")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Login Partial View page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ...Some Code...
}
else
{
    ...Some Code...
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

LoginPartial View Code

```
@using WebPortal.Models
@model LoginViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form class="login-form margin-clear">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <i class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-gray btn-sm" />
        <span class="pl-5 pr-5">or</span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-sm" })
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList")
    </form>
}
```

ExternalLogin List Code

```
@model WebPortal.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security
@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    if (loginProviders.Count() == 0)
    {
        <span class="text-center">No External Logins</span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span>Login with&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                {
                    switch (@p.AuthenticationType)
                    {
                        case "Facebook":
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xsm facebook" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
                            break;
                        case "Twitter":
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xsm twitter" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button>
                            break;
                        case "Google":
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xsm googleplus" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></button>
                            break;
                        case "Microsoft":
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xsm microsoft" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></button>
                            break;
                        default:
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xsm" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType">@p.AuthenticationType.ToString()</button>
                            break;
                    }
                }
            </span>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `@Html.Partial()` and don't provide it a model, it uses the current (or parent, if you want to think of it that way) model instead. So when you do

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList")
```

Without the second parameter to specify the model, it provides the current one. You should be providing a view model to the partial like so:

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList", externalLoginsViewModel)
```

Otherwise you'll provide the current one, which is not the same type that is expected by the partial.

Answer (score 0):

The ExternalLoginList partial expects a model to be passed to it.

```
@model WebPortal.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
```

You need to pass the model in here:

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList")
```

Like this:

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList", new ExternalLoginListViewModel())
```

**OR**

Put the partial's model in the parent's model

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public ExternalLoginListViewModel externalLoginListViewModel;
}
```

and pass it to the partial.

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/_ExternalLoginsList", externalLoginListViewModel)
```

**OR**

I don't see any references to the model in the ExternalLoginList partial so you can probably just delete this line:

```
@model WebPortal.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
```